# Why is the Caption ignored for JavaScript Add-Ins in Navision for Windows Client?

Tags: javascript, navision

i have a Page in Navision with a field, which includes a JavaScript control addin. I am new to Navision and I am wondering, why is the `Caption` and `CaptionML` attribute ignored. The property `ShowCaption` is set to `Yes`. In the picture below you can see all properties of the field.

Also setting the caption in the control addin is not a option in my case.

[Properties of the field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec2kk.png)

Comment: when you execute NAV client language is ENU or DEU?

Comment: As default I use DEU, but the Problem appears in both languages.